# Sanitize a database during Arquillian testing

Tags: java, mongodb, testing, morphia, jboss-arquillian

I am currently writing tests for some REST-full Services I wrote.  The services I am testing are written in Java and use MongoDb/Morphia.  The tests call on the services, some of which in turn write to a test collection.  I need to clean up after the tests and delete the data I injected.  What is the best way to go about this?

Here is an example of one of my simple services:

```
package org.haib.myerslab.services;

@Path("/database")
public class DatabaseService {
    @Inject
    private Datastore ds;

    @Path("/genre/")
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public GenreDTO postFromGenreDTO(@Context UriInfo uri, GenreDTO form) throws ParseException {
        Genre myNewGenre = DtoToDomainMapper.gerneFromGenreDTO(form);
        myNewGenre.setId(form.getId());
        ds.save(myNewGenre);
        return new GenreDTO(myNewGenre);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of my Arquillian test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GeneTest {
    private static String myId = "myGenreId";
    private static String myGenre = "myGenre";
    private static String myGenreInfo = "myGenreInfo";

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive getDeployment() {
        return TestHelper.getDeployment();
    }

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    @InSequence(1)
    public void canPostGenre(@ArquillianResource URL baseURL) throws Exception {
        GenreDTO newGenre = new GenreDTO();
        newGenre.setGenre(myGenre);
        newGenre.setGenreInfo(myGenreInfo);
        newGenre.setId(myId);

        String url = baseURL.toURI().resolve("/database/genre/").toString();
        JsonNode rootNode = TestHelper.postUrl(url, newGene);

        assertEquals(myGenre,     rootNode.get("genre").asText());
        assertEquals(myGenreInfo, rootNode.get("genreInfo").asText());
        assertEquals(myId,        rootNode.get("id").asText());
    } 
}
```

Where the getDeployment function looks like this:

```
public static WebArchive getDeployment() {
    File[] depend = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClass(TestHelper.class)
        .addClass(Genre.class).addClass(Application.class).addPackage("org/haib/myerslab")
        .addPackage("org/haib/myerslab/database").addPackage("org/haib/myerslab/genre")
        .addPackage("org/haib/myerslab/dto").addPackage("org/haib/myerslab/dto/genre")
        .addAsLibraries(depend).addAsWebInfResource("jboss-deployment-structure.xml")
        .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml").setWebXML("test-web.xml");
    return war;
}
```

So where I am lost is, what is the best way to Inject the database in an @After, and clear our the Genre Class I posted into it so that my next test doesn't have it there.
How should I do this? Is there another way?

Comment: +1, Good to see that somebody is looking for good practises for integration tests.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [nosql-unit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit). It provides annotations and rules that help you with seeding datasets, comparing expectations and cleaning up MongoDB.

To get your MongoDB into a pristine state before executing a test, you can simply use the following Annotation with the `CLEAN_INSERT´ :

```
@UsingDataSet(locations="my_data_set.json", loadStrategy=LoadStrategyEnum.CLEAN_INSERT) 
public void canPostGenre() { ...}
```

If you need the behavior around the integration testing lifecycle with MongoDB to be more powerful, you can also roll your own based on the ideas of nosql-unit. Also make sure to check out [Junit Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules).